# Not Getting Complete Data from Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio-3.0

I have created some users and their children in Firebase Database and I also have populated it but when I am reading from the database, it gives me incomplete data. I have a 
database > ExpenseManager > user > expenses. I am retrieving data from expenses. expenses contains 3 duplicate values continuously, I have total 10 entries but when I am retrieving I get only 9 entries. One of the Three duplicate values is missing. I am using for each loop inside childEventListener > onChildAdded().

```
 database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("ExpenseManager");

    mChildEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshots : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                expenseTestModelValues = (ExpenseTestModel) dataSnapshot.getValue(ExpenseTestModel.class);
                readValue.setText(expenseTestModelValues.getExpName()
                        +"\n "+expenseTestModelValues.getExpType()
                        +"\n "+expenseTestModelValues.getExpAmt()
                        +"\n "+expenseTestModelValues.getDate()
                        +"\n "+expenseTestModelValues.getMonth()
                        +"\n "+expenseTestModelValues.getYear());

            }


            Log.e(TAG,expenseTestModelValues.getExpName()
                    +"\n "+expenseTestModelValues.getExpType()
                    +"\n "+expenseTestModelValues.getExpAmt()
                    +"\n "+expenseTestModelValues.getDate()
                    +"\n "+expenseTestModelValues.getMonth()
                    +"\n "+expenseTestModelValues.getYear());

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    };
    myRef.child(currentUser.getUid()).child("expenses").addChildEventListener(mChildEventListener);
```

Here is the Image of Data base
[image: Databse Image.]

The log is also printing only 9 entries instead of 10.
And if I have all the entries same then it gives me only 2 entries when I read from database.
I have tried ValueEventListener also. But getting same problem. 
Please Help !!!.

ExpenseTestModel

```
package com.nkbw.expensemanager.test;
```

public class ExpenseTestModel {

```
String date;
String month;
String year;
String expName;
String expType;

public ExpenseTestModel() {

}

public ExpenseTestModel(String date, String month, String year, String expName, String expType, String expAmt) {
    this.date = date;
    this.month = month;
    this.year = year;
    this.expName = expName;
    this.expType = expType;
    this.expAmt = expAmt;
}

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public String getMonth() {
    return month;
}

public void setMonth(String month) {
    this.month = month;
}

public String getYear() {
    return year;
}

public void setYear(String year) {
    this.year = year;
}

public String getExpName() {
    return expName;
}

public void setExpName(String expName) {
    this.expName = expName;
}

public String getExpType() {
    return expType;
}

public void setExpType(String expType) {
    this.expType = expType;
}

public String getExpAmt() {
    return expAmt;
}

public void setExpAmt(String expAmt) {
    this.expAmt = expAmt;
}

String expAmt;
```

}

Here is the Image of Last Three entries. Last Second and last third is having same values. so I am only getting One of the Last Second and third Entries not both.
I have total 10 entries and I getting only 9. Why is that so.
[image: Here the image of database with values]

Comment: You are trying to access `expenses` ? can you show you `ExpenseTestModel`

Comment: yes I  am accessing expenses. I am adding the ExpenseTestModel in the post. @frankenstein

Comment: Are able to store data in this `ExpenseTestModel()` ?

Comment: yes. It is even stored in firebase database

Comment: problem is that, if i have multiple duplicate data and when I read those values I don't get the total entries from database @frankenstein

Comment: `for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshots : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                expenseTestModelValues = (ExpenseTestModel) dataSnapshot.getValue(ExpenseTestModel.class);` you are iterating here, but you are not using `dataSnapshots` with an `s`

Comment: dataSnapshots is my variable which stores the values from dataSnapshot.getChildren(). and then i am iterating through the list using dataSnapshots @PeterHaddad

Comment: yes but you are not using `dataSnapshots`, so its useless. Check this line     `expenseTestModelValues = (ExpenseTestModel) dataSnapshot.getValue(ExpenseTestModel.class);`

Comment: And if that was a problem then I would not have got any values. But  I am not getting  only duplicate values. Why is that so  ?? @PeterHaddad

Comment: okk I got it. Let me try @PeterHaddad

Comment: It is giving me this exception when I used **dataSnapshots** `com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.nkbw.expensemanager.test.ExpenseTestModel`@PeterHaddad

Comment: You cannot access expenses. You missed child expenses. Replace with this one. `expenseTestModelValues = (ExpenseTestModel) dataSnapshots.child("expenses").getValue(ExpenseTestModel.class);`

Comment: It is giving Null Pointer Exception `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.nkbw.expensemanager.test.ExpenseTestModel.getExpName()' on a null object reference` @Ticherhaz

Comment: Why do you say that three of them are the same? I see 10 different items.

Comment: items are different but their values are exact Same. I have tested this, when all values were different I was getting all entries in my database read. then I gave the alternate duplicate values then also i was getting all entries from database read. but when 2 or more values are duplicate one after another then. I dont get all the entries from read operation. Let me upload a pic in edit so u can see @AlexMamo

Comment: @Nomankhanbhai Have you tried Peter's recommendation?

Comment: after trying peters recommendation I got this `com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.nkbw.expensemanager.test.ExpenseTestModel` and then I tried `expenseTestModelValues = (ExpenseTestModel) dataSnapshots.child("expenses").getValue(ExpenseTestModel.class);` so it gave me this exception `ava.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.nkbw.expensemanager.test.ExpenseTestModel.getExpName()' on a null object reference` @AlexMamo

Comment: Any Idea how can I fix this issue. Please Help!! @AlexMamo

Comment: Any Idea how can I fix this issue. Please Help!! @Ticherhaz

Comment: Any Idea how can I fix this issue. Please Help!! @PeterHaddad

Comment: Any Idea how can I fix this issue. Please Help!! @frankenstein

Comment: @Nomankhanbhai you are not able to get only duplicate data ?

Comment: Yes you got it. But how do i fix it please help @frankenstein

Comment: @Nomankhanbhai you want to teamviewer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

Create list to store all data

```
   List<ExpenseTestModel> list=new ArrayList();
```

Now store data in list

```
   myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
           list.clear();
        for (DataSnapshot childDataSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
         ExpenseTestModel     expenseTestModelValues = (ExpenseTestModel) dataSnapshot.getValue(ExpenseTestModel.class);
         list.add(expenseTestModelValues);
        }
     // Now  print size of list
    Log.e("list size",":"+list.size()); 
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException();
    }
});
```

Comment: same problem. getting 9 entries out of 10 @frankenstein

Comment: Ok. add counter  and check how many time `for loop ' is executing .

Comment: @Nomankhanbhai i just tried create issue like you though duplicate data. But issue doesn't appear .It mean  nothing wrong with `firebase` some thing  your `code` . I just updated  my answer .let me know  if you are still having same issue.

Comment: Thank you so much sir. It worked !!!. But when I am printing count in log then it is giving me compelete list. else same problem exists. Don't know why. But your method worked and helped me . @frankenstein